# Android Hidden API backward compatibility

Tags: android, api, hidden

I am building an app for our lab experiment (no intentions of releasing on google play). The app requires use of Android's hidden API. I found an app on google play store that is doing similar stuff by using those hidden APIs.

The app has min and target sdk versions set to 3 and 7 respectively. However, when I tried this app on my emulater (AVD running API 18) the app still works.

However, when I used those hidden APIs (in my app) I came to know that one of the API has been discarded. So I am confused how come that app is still working. If Android is maintaining backward compatibility (even for hidden APIs), then is there a way I can make use of it?

I built my appl against API 7 and tested on AVD running API 7 and it worked. Then I took the apk file (from the bin folder) and deployed on AVD running latest API (18) but it didn't work.

Can anyone please give me some pointers on how can I make my app work on latest API?

Thanks!

Comment: what hidden API are you talking about, what does the stack trace say

Comment: You got to be more clear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().registerActivityWatcher - This function registerActivityWatcher has been dropped

Comment: I didn't want to include details because I thought it might change discussion to something like - I should not be using hidden api or this is not allowed etc. I want to know how come an app from google play store is able to use this hidden api (which has been dropped) in latest version (API level 18) but my app fails